# MYSQL Subquery on the same table with Group By Clauses...

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

having what's probably another simple left/right join with mysql... but it's a bit complex and all the examples I've seen so far I can't seem to make work with what I have. I apologize if this is a bit confusing... I'm going to try to really spell it out. Basically, there's three SELECT queries that are selecting data from the SAME table. There's only four fields I'm interacting with in a table called '**Order_Items**' which is:

- '**Item**' - The Item name, however this CAN be blank, when it is I need to get:
- '**Essential_Type**' - The alternate Item Name
- '**QTY**' - Which is how many have been ordered of that item that was ordered in the particular order. Now, if **Item** is blank, I need to **COUNT(Essential_Type)** instead of **SUM(QTY)** because **QTY** for those rows is Null, but that row needs to be counted as 1
- '**Created**' - The DateTime of the order creation

---

Query #1: This gets me the Name of the item and how many were Sold

```
SELECT 
 IF(Item='', Essential_Type, Item) AS Name,
 IF(Item='', COUNT(Essential_Type), SUM(QTY)) AS Qty
 FROM Order_Items
 GROUP BY Item, Essential_Type
 ORDER BY Qty
```

Returns:

```
NAME          QTY
---------------------
8x10          2345
16x20         340
```

---

Query #2: This gets me the number of each item sold THIS year

```
SELECT 
 IF(Item='', Essential_Type, Item) AS Name,
 IF(Item='', COUNT(Essential_Type), SUM(QTY)) AS ThisYear
 FROM Order_Items
 WHERE year(Created)=2016
 GROUP BY Item, Essential_Type
```

Returns:

```
Name          ThisYear
-----------------------------
8x10          120
16x20         25
```

---

Query #3: This gets me the number of each item sold LAST year

```
SELECT 
 IF(Item='', Essential_Type, Item) AS Name,
 IF(Item='', COUNT(Essential_Type), SUM(QTY)) AS LastYear
 FROM Order_Items
 WHERE year(Created)=2015
 GROUP BY Item, Essential_Type
```

Returns:

```
Name          LastYear
-----------------------------
8x10          500
16x20         30
```

---

---

So if **Order_Items** looks like this for example:

```
Item           Essential_Type           QTY       Created
---------------------------------------------------------------------
8x10                                    3         2016-09-01
8x10                                    1         2015-07-21
               16x20                    NULL      2015-08-12
               16x20                    NULL      2016-05-21
```

How can I combine those three somewhat complex SELECTs into one SELECT statement using a JOIN? Basically so the final result would be (based on the above sample table):

```
Name          QTY         ThisYear        LastYear
-----------------------------------------------------------
8x10          4           3               1
16x20         2           1               1
```

Thanks for reading and any potential help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the logic for the aggregation awkward (I suspect that the query would be simpler using `UNION ALL`).  But, you can extend your query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Item = '' THEN Essential_Type ELSE Item END) AS Name,
       (CASE WHEN Item = '' THEN COUNT(Essential_Type) ELSE SUM(QTY) END) AS Qty,
       (CASE WHEN Item = ''
             THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(Created) = 2015 THEN Essential_Type END)
             ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Created) = 2015 THEN QTY END)
        END) as yr2015,
       (CASE WHEN Item = ''
             THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(Created) = 2016 THEN Essential_Type END)
             ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Created) = 2016 THEN QTY END)
        END) as yr2016
FROM Order_Items
GROUP BY Item, Essential_Type
ORDER BY Qty;
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Yes, the data in this particular table is really jumbled inefficiently, but I'm forced to use it as is without rearranging the data which I would rather have done. Thank you for the answer, that helps quite a lot.